# Is there a 'test start' for mocha reporter?

Tags: mocha.js

I'm editing a [mocha reporter](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters) and I'm wondering if there's something like `runner.on('test end'...` but 
something that occurs at the beginning of each test, something like  `runner.on('test start'...` is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `'test'`

```
runner.on('test', function(test) {
    // test beginning
});
```